# Comparing two object values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

How do I compare two object values in an array?

My web page consists of a quiz with multiple input questions. The user's input `userinput` is saved to an `array` which already contains the questions stem `q` and the answer `ans`.

Array:

```
var questions = [
    [{
      "q": "What is the capital of England?",
      "ans": "london",
      "userinput": "london"
    }, {
      "q": "What is the capital of Ireland?",
      "ans": "dublin",
      "userinput": "dublin"
    }, {
      "q": "What is the capital of France?",
      "ans": "paris",
      "userinput": "paris"
    }, {
      "q": "What is the captial of Spain?",
      "ans": "london",
      "userinput": "madrid"
    }],
    [
      [{
          "q": ...
```

I'm not sure how to create the comparsion `if` statement. Here's what I tried. It displays the console message `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

I've included `[$slide]` and `[$qnum]` so i reuse code on other pages.

```
if ($(questions[$slide][$qnum].userinput.val()) === $(questions[$slide][$qnum].ans.val())
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need jQuery here. You need to select the question in the `array` by `index` and then just use `userinput` and `ans` property of the question `object`.

```
if( questions[$slide][$qnum].userinput) === questions[$slide][$qnum].ans )
```

Example:

```js
var questions = [
    [{
        q         : "What is the capital of England?",
        ans       : "london",
        userinput : "london"
    }]
];

if( questions[0][0].userinput === questions[0][0].ans ) {
    console.log("match");
}
```